# Is it possible to run try statement in a loop if any error comes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, try-except

If some error comes then it goes to `except` statement after the `try` one, where the program ends. My question is, Is it possible, that if an error comes then without ending the program it runs the try statement continuously?

For example :

```
try:
    some error caught
except:
    go to try statement again
```

And this runs continuously in a chain?

Comment: Sounds like you might want recursion. Look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059566/python-try-except-else-with-recursion).

Comment: You can include a try-except in a while- or for-loop.

Comment: Yeah i did put in a while loop, but when an error comes, it ends the program : (

Comment: please try to provide the smallest working example, that reproduces the error.

If this is not possible, then show  the error message, that you get.

Comment: I just answered my own question, and worked perfectly in my case. Thanks for your help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a loop, that breaks if no exception occurs

```
while True:
   try:
       some_code_that_might_fail
    except Exception:  # catch all potential errors 
        continue  # if exception occured continue the loop
    break  # if no exception occured break out of the loop
```

Pls try out following example:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("please enter a number"))
        print("The number is ", num)
        rec = 1 / num
    except Exception:
        print("either you entered no number or 0 (or some other error occured)")
        continue  # if any exception occured continue the loop
    break  # if no exception occured break out of the loop

print("1 / %f = %f" % (num, rec))
```

As Bruno mentioned. 
In general (and this is what I do in my own code) it is not suggested to catch all exceptions.

You should catch only known exceptions explicitly

**Addendum 2020-04-17**

Reading your answer I think your question is a little misleading.
What is perhaps your problem is, that you have a function, that you would like to run forever.
However sometimes the function terminates (due to an error) **without** raising an exception.

IF this is the case then just write:

```
while True:
   afunc()
   print("function terminated. I will restart it")
```

but note, that your program will never terminate.

or if the function sometimes raises an exception and sometimes doesn't but just terminates and you'd like to call the function whenever it failed or terminated, then do.

```
while True:
   try:
      afunc()
      print("function terminated without exception")

   except Exception:
      pass
      print("function encountered an exception")
   print("will restart")
```

If you want, that function can terminate and you have the means to find out whether it was an error or not, then you could do something like:

```
while True:
   try:
      afunc()
      if i_know_that_func_terminated_correctly():
          print("function terminated correctly")
          break
      print("function terminated without an error")

   except Exception:
      pass
      print("function terminated with an exception")
   print("restarting")
```

I added print statements for debugging / visualizing. Just remove them or comment them if not needed. (That's also why I left the `pass` statement 
in the `except` clause)

Comment: I just tried your code and if error comes It again ends the program : (

Comment: Perhaps your code does not raise an exception, but calls  calls `os._exit()` on error

This cannot be caught with `try:` / `except:`


I will show you in an example, that above code works for exceptions.

You might want to post the error message that you get.

there might be tricks with monkeypatching or mocks but we need more info about your exact problem

Comment: Please do NOT post example code with bare except clauses - those are PURE EVIL.

Comment: In the given context I assume to be pure evil.
The question asks explicitly to repeat on all errors. (to catch all errors)
I can add `Exception` though.

However I added a comment to my answer

Comment: also changed the code to make it more obvious, that ALL exceptions are caught

Comment: funny: got an undownvote, followed by a downvote within the same minute.
Unfortunately no comment. 
I'd like to improve the answer if possible, but commentless voting doesn't help to do this